# Problems using OpenCV,Python and NAOqi

Tags: python, opencv, nao-robot

I am analysing Webcam images of an connect4 game to send information to a NAO Robot, because i want to make him play the game.

Here comes the Problem:

My OpenCV codes only runs on OpenCV Versions that only support Python3.x but the NAO Robots SDK for Python only works with Python 2.7. So with one Version of Python my Computervision Works and with the other Version i can connect with the Robot -.-

Maybe some of you know a solution or at least a good workaroung.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sounds like they should update the NAO Robots to run a version of Python that hasn't been deprecated for the past 10 years.

Comment: Worst comes to worst you'll have to look into inter-process communication to have one program talk to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try communicate with NAO using libqi instead.

```
pip install qi
```

That is what is underneath the NAOqi SDK.

[Here is the documentation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/libqi/).

In a nutshell, wherever you would use an `ALProxy(...)`, instead you would retrieve get a service from a session with `session->service(...)`.